# ANTLR4 under eclipse generates sources inside incorrect packages

Tags: eclipse, antlr4

I'm trying to convert my project to antlr4. I converted grammar, but i can't generated sources to correct package.

When I run build, Eclipse placed generated sources in incorrect packages. If i place my grammar directly inside `src/`, sources are generating inside `default` package. If i move my grammar to be inside package `my.sources.package`, Eclipse generates correctly entire package structure, but it place it relatively to place where is the grammar `my.sources.package.my.sources.package`.

If that helps, i'm using Eclipse Luna 4.4.2, antlr4ide 0.3.5 and Antler 4.4

Answer (score 3):

Don't put the grammar files inside a Java package.  Add 'folders' under src with the path you want to create for the package name.

In the project properties, go to ANTLR4 -> Tool and set the desired output directory in the Options -> Directory field.

Attached is a screenshot showing the directory structure and properties window.

[Screenshot showing directory structure and properties window](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gs55O.png)